# JSF validation messages not displayed after deployment

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

All the JSF 2.0 validation and required messages are working on my local VM but after deployment in Development environment they are not displayed. I used Maven for building in Development and RAD in my local. I'm using WAS 8.5.

I’ve verified that both local and Dev have same code deployed. Please let me know if anything else is required.

```
Code for one field:

<h:inputText styleClass="inputs" id="assessmentStation" size="3" 
        maxlength="3"                                                                                                    
        validatorMessage="Assessment Station must be 3 digits" 
        required="true" requiredMessage="Assessment Station must be entered"
                   onkeypress="return  myFunction(event)">                                                                             
      <f:validateRegex pattern="[0-9]{3}"></f:validateRegex>
      <p:ajax event="blur" update="assessmentStationMsg"></p:ajax>
</h:inputText> 

<h:message id="assessmentStationMsg" for="assessmentStation"> </h:message>
```

It looks like the validations are not rendered in HTML:
Below is HTML generated:

```
<td style="width: 5px"> </td>
                    <td><input id="form2:assessmentStation" 
  name="form2:assessmentStation" type="text" value="" onkeypress="return` 
  myFunction(event)" 
  onblur="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;form2:assessmentStation&quot;,e:&quot;blur&quot;,p:&quot;form2:assessmentStation&quot;,u:&quot;form2:assessmentStationMsg&quot;}) ;" maxlength="3" size="3" class="inputs" /><span 
 id="form2:assessmentStationMsg"></span>
</td>
```

Comment: Does it work if you use an f:ajax? And the generated html is for the input, not the 'message'

Comment: I tried with f:ajax also but no luck. f:ajax was displaying messages on console in my local VM and no messages displayed on Dev server. I found similar issue for wblogic : https://issues.liferay.com/browse/FACES-1591?_ga=2.73232666.849990635.1527882285-788190244.1527882285

I've my session managed bean implementing serializable now. That did not help either.

Comment: On console??? That is not good either...

Comment: I'm getting serverError-javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException using f:ajax on dev server.

Comment: That is completely different than your title. Several Q/A in stackoverflow on that

Comment: I'm getting this exception when I use f:ajax, when I use p:ajax I dont get exception but messages are not displayed.